# Random Variables Expectation Product

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Can I say that $E[XY^2] = E[X]*E[Y^2]$? I know that $E[XY] = E[X]*E[Y]$ but does this still hold true if a random variable is squared?

Comment: What's $*$? And if you know the first equality holds (whatever it means) for any random variables $X$ and $Y$, why can't you just replace $Y$ by $Y^2$ to get the second equality?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?  There are counter-examples if they are merely uncorrelated

Comment: Yes they are independent.

Comment: I believe the answer is Yes; because of linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}E(XY^2) &= \int \int xy^2 P(x,y) \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int \int xy^2 P(x) P(y) \, dx \, dy & \text{ (as the they are independent)}\\
& = \int x P(x) dx\int y^2 P(y)dy \\
& = E(X) E(Y^2) \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: If $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ are independent random variables and for $i=1,2,...,n,$ the expectation $\mathbb{E}[f_i(X_i)]$ exists then:$$\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_i(X_i)\right]=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[f_i(X_i)].$$
Proof is similar to @kasa's answer. It can be proved more general:

Theorem:$X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ are mutually independent $\Longleftrightarrow$  $$\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_i(X_i)\right]=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[f_i(X_i)]$$
for eny $n$ function $f_i$ such that the  expected values exist and are well-defined